# How can I write this SQL while loop code to get an XML results in one line instead of 3 separate lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get all this XML result in one line instead of 3 for each column

```
DECLARE @ii INT = 10;
DECLARE @String1 NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @String1 = '';

WHILE(@ii <= 18)
BEGIN
    SET @String1 = (@String1 + 'SELECT LoanNumber = ''Complaint'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@ii)+'-Call1''  , LoanStatus=''Compliants''   , LoanStatusDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    UNION
    SELECT LoanNumber = ''Complaint'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@ii)+'-Call2'', LoanStatus=''Compliants'' , LoanStatusDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    UNION
    SELECT LoanNumber = ''Complaint'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@ii)+'-Call3'', LoanStatus=''Compliants'' , LoanStatusDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)')

    IF @ii != 18
        SET @string1 = @string1 + ' UNION '
    ELSE 
        SET @string1 = @string1 + 'FOR XML PATH (''Loan''),ROOT(''Loans'') '

    SET @ii = @ii+1     
END

EXEC sp_executesql @String1
```

I want something like this:

```
<Loans>
    <LoanNumber>Complaint10-Call1<LoanStatus>Compliants<LoanStatusDate>2019-01-18
  </Loan>
  <Loan>
    <LoanNumber>Complaint10-Call2 <LoanStatus>Compliants<LoanStatusDate>2019-01-18
  </Loan>
  <Loan>
    <LoanNumber>Complaint10-Call3<LoanStatus>Compliants<LoanStatusDate>2019-01-18
  </Loan>
```

Instead of the result that you get when you execute the code I provided. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What version of SQL? And I'm guessing SQL Server, correct? Also, can you provide some example input data?

Comment: @shawn SQL server 2014.  if you run the code you will see the result.  no input data is needed . I just want the structure of the xml outcome to all be on one line for one set of each loop.

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to figure out the practical application of this. I'm not sure that your example replicates real-world application of what you ultimately want to do. This is essentially generating 3 duplicate rows but just changing a Call #. If you were actually querying for Calls, you wouldn't need the loops. Your query would handle it. If you need to use the loop, you may be able to do it with another inside loop, but you're still applying Call1, Call2 and Call3 to your rows.

Comment: Mozee, the "XML" you provide as *"I want something like this .... instead of the result..."* is absolutely invalid XML. Are you sure you need this the way you show us? Quite probably, you won't  need a `WHILE` loop, neither dynamic XML... Try to set up a [mcve] with minimal sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @Mozee you don't need loops in SQL, You don't need loops to work with XML either. Your code looks like an attempt to generate 18 XML elements with incrementing numbers. You don't need a loop for that, only a table (table variable, temp table, CTE, a Numbers table or a row constructor in FRROM) with values from 1 to 18 and a simple `FOR XML` query on top of it.

Comment: `in one line instead of 3 for each column` that's meaningless in XML. The whitespace outside elements is ignored. On top of that, SQL Server has an explicit `XML` type. What you see is how SSMS formats an `xml` value. How you convert that to a string is up to your application

Answer (score 1):

This might be wild guessing, but I've got the feeling, that I understand, what this is about:

> if you run the code you will see the result. no input data is needed .
>   I just want the structure of the xml outcome to all be on one line for
>   one set of each loop

Your provided code leads to this:

```
<Loans>
  <Loan>
    <LoanNumber>Complaint10-Call1</LoanNumber>
    <LoanStatus>Compliants</LoanStatus>
    <LoanStatusDate>2019-01-22</LoanStatusDate>
  </Loan>
  <Loan>
    <LoanNumber>Complaint10-Call2</LoanNumber>
    <LoanStatus>Compliants</LoanStatus>
    <LoanStatusDate>2019-01-22</LoanStatusDate>
  </Loan>
  <!-- more of them-->
</Loans>
```

This is perfectly okay, valid XML.

But you want the result

> outcome to all be on one line for one set of each loop

Something like this?

```
<Loans>
  <Loan>
    <LoanNumber>Complaint10-Call1</LoanNumber><LoanStatus>Compliants</LoanStatus><LoanStatusDate>2019-01-22</LoanStatusDate>
  </Loan>
  <!-- more of them-->
</Loans>
```

There is a big misconception I think... XML is not the thing *you see*. The same XML can look quite differently, without any semantic difference:

Check this out:

```
DECLARE @xmltable table(SomeXml XML)
INSERT INTO @xmltable VALUES
                        --the whole in one line
                        ('<root><a>test</a><a>test2</a></root>')

                        --all <a>s in one line
                       ,('<root>
                          <a>test</a><a>test2</a>
                          </root>')

                       --each element in one line
                       ,('<root>
                          <a>test</a>
                          <a>test2</a>
                          </root>')

                       --white space going wild...
                       ,('<root>
                                                <a>test</a>
    <a>test2</a>
                                         </root>');

--now check the results                                          
SELECT * FROM @xmltable;
```

This means: How the XML appears is a matter of the interpreter. The same XML opened with another tool might appear differently. Dealing with XML means *dealing with data but not with format*... The actual format has no meaning and should not matter at all...

Starting with SQL-Server 2016 you might have a look at JSON, if you need a *tiny* format:

```
DECLARE @somedata table(SomeValue VARCHAR(100),SomeStatus VARCHAR(100),SomeDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @somedata VALUES
 ('Complaint10-Call1','Complaints','2019-01-22')
,('Complaint10-Call2','Complaints','2019-01-22')
,('Complaint10-Call3','Complaints','2019-01-22');

SELECT * FROM @somedata FOR JSON PATH;
```

The result comes in *one line*:

```
[{"SomeValue":"Complaint10-Call1","SomeStatus":"Complaints","SomeDate":"2019-01-22"},{"SomeValue":"Complaint10-Call2","SomeStatus":"Complaints","SomeDate":"2019-01-22"},{"SomeValue":"Complaint10-Call3","SomeStatus":"Complaints","SomeDate":"2019-01-22"}]
```